# Is it possible to wait until multiprocessing.Value changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a simple bool value to tell subprocess to clean up and gracefully exit:

```
self.mem_manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
self.exiting = self..mem_manager.Value(ctypes.c_byte, False)
```

Now I have a bunch of threads doing the actual work, so right now at the end of my `run()` method for my process there was basically this:

```
while not self.exiting.value:
    time.sleep(1)
self.terminate_threads()
return
```

This is really ugly. Whenever I was dealing with that, there was a condition variable to wait on.

But I have another condition for quitting already - failure in either thread. So I now have a condition variable:

```
error_condition = threading.Condition()
... threads have access to this and will notify on error and stop ...

... more code ...

while not self.exiting.value:
    with error_condition:
        error_condition.wait(1)
        if self.errors_happened():
            ... handle errors ...
            break
self.terminate_threads()
return
```

I would prefer of course:

```
while not self.exiting.value:
    wait_for_either(error_contition, changed_condition(self.exiting))
```

Can I do that somehow?

Comment: Why not use a multiprocessing.Event instead of a manager.Value?  You can wait on the former but not on the latter.

Comment: who is changing the value ? is it python or some C extension ? in python you'd use `multiprocessing.connection.wait` to wait for multiple conditions, but a C value cannot be waited on, so you must attach an event to this value.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Both is python, but note that one is a multithreading condition and the other is a multiprocessing shared variable. They don't seem to be sharing any API to wait on both.

Comment: _This is really ugly. Whenever I was dealing with that, there was a condition variable to wait on._ Then, why do you use a `multiprocessing.Value` and not `multiprocessing.Condition`?